# where is the official c++ documentation

Tags: c++

I've been programming in c++ for a while but I still haven't found any official documentation (like http://ruby-doc.org/). Right now I am using websites like http://en.cppreference.com/w/. Oh and lasty the thing that caused me to write this is I always find documentation that uses outdated libraries and other junk and I can't find any documentation that uses features of c++11 and 14

Comment: The link you posted has tons of C++11 and C++14 info.

Comment: The official documentation can be bought here: https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Comment: The current working draft is [on GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) (in its LaTeX sources). The published standards are cut from the working draft every so often.

Comment: Ruby-Doc isn't any more official than CPP Reference is - they're both maintained by a third-party community.

Comment: C++ is not a product and there is no company behind it. So there is no official documentation. C++ is a **Standard**. You can download the C++ standard text ( [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) ), and/or documentations on implementations of the standard, which are compiler suits (gcc, icc, clang, msvc, etc.).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page is the open documentation for c plus plus, if you want latest docs you have to pay for them to ISO, however you can also check the official repos of development progress at GitHub at https://www.GitHub.com/cplusplus

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The official C++ "documentation" is the C++ standard, ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E). There is information at [ISOCPP](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) how to obtain the document.

I wouldn't necessarily consider the standard good documentation but it does specify the behavior of the standard language and library constructs.

There isn't any other *official* document on C++ describing the entire language. There are good derivative works making things more accessible like Bjarne Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles as Practices Using C++" and Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library".